# How can I join an array with from and to?

Tags: ruby

I have an array, I would like to concat all values except the first one element.

For example: Doing it on the array
`[1,2,3,4,5]` should output `2345`

I tried to do it with `row.join("")` but I could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: I think you mean that `"2345"` (not `2345`) is to be returned. Be precise!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try these

```
[1,2,3,4,5].drop(1).join
=> "2345"

[1,2,3,4,5][1..-1].join
=> "2345"
```

Comment: With recent versions of Ruby you can write `[1,2,3,4,5][1..].join` (or `[1,2,3,4,5].join[1..]`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Didn't know! Interestingly enough `[1,2,3,4,5][1...].join` (3 dots) gives the same result.

Comment: That's because the concept of "inclusive" and "exclusive" doesn't apply to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Your question almost certainly just suffers from poor formatting, but if you actually want a number back rather than a string, you could do something like:

```
irb(main):018:0> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):019:0> num = 0
irb(main):020:0> a.drop(1).reverse.each_with_index { |digit, i| num += digit * 10 ** i }
=> [5, 4, 3, 2]
irb(main):021:0> num
=> 2345
```

Or perhaps:

```
irb(main):033:0> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):034:0> a.drop(1).reverse.each_with_index.reduce(0) { |acc, (x, i)| acc + x * 10 ** i }
=> 2345
```

Comment: You can reduce the number of temporary arrays by one (to one) by writing `a.drop(1).reverse_each.with_index.reduce(0) { |acc, (x, i)| acc + x * 10 ** i }`, but isn't `a.drop(1).join.to_i` a lot simpler?

Comment: `a[1..].inject{|res, d| res * 10 + d }` seems to work without reversing and exponentiation.

Comment: This seems overly complicated.  If the required output should be in number form, why not just use ```[1,2,3,4,5].drop(1).join.to_i```?

Comment: I was trying to avoid string manipulation. Alternative suggestions have been made by some very smart people that accomplish that in more clever ways than I did.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using the `*` or "splat" operator and `multiple_assignments`:

```
dropped, *kept =  [1,2,3,4,5]
kept.join
#=>  "2345"
```

The splat can be used to deconstruct the array in a plethora of other ways as well such as:

```
drop, drop, *keep =  [1,2,3,4,5]
keep  #=>  [3, 4, 5]

*keep, drop =  [1,2,3,4,5]
keep  #=>  [1, 2, 3, 4]

first,*middle, last =  [1,2,3,4,5]
first #=>  1
middle  #=>  [2, 3, 4]
last  #=>  5
```

...just to name a few

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
yourList = [1,2,3,4,5]
yourList.shift
puts "#{yourList.join("")}\n\n"
```

OUTPUT: 2345

Comment: Be careful, `shift` modifies the original array.